# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel when publishing Self-contained application

Tags: ssl, .net-core, build

Im building my application with these profile settings:[image]

When I build it, the console outputs this:

```
2>An error occurred while sending the request.
2>  The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
2>Unable to get repository signature information for source https://api.nuget.org/v3-index/repository-signatures/5.0.0/index.json.
2>  An error occurred while sending the request.
2>  The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

I've seen answers that tell you to change `DisabledByDefault` in
`\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Client`
but i do not have `TLS 1.3` in `Protocols`, only `SSL 2.0`.

I have updated .NET to 5.0.1 and .NET CORE to 3.1.404 and that has not helped.